# Unhelpful error in data.table merge of identical schema tables

Tags: r, data.table

When trying to merge the following two data tables, I'm encountering an unhelpful error

```
dt.1=data.table(col1=1:10, col2="A", col3="A")
dt.2=data.table(col1=1:15, col2="A", col3="A")
merge(dt.1,dt.2,all=T, by=c("col1","col3"))
# Error in setcolorder(yy, names(dt)) :
# x has some duplicated column name(s): col2.. 
# Please remove or rename the duplicate(s) and try again.
```

While `merge.data.frame` works without error.

Relevant bits of `sessionInfo` below:

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)  
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)  
data.table_1.9.2
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Works fine for me on 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 (R v3.0.3).

Comment: I see.. Does `merge` depend on the reference behavior of `names.data.table`? The problem only occurs after the following override: `names.data.table <- function(x) copy(attributes(x)$names)` based on the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792197/r-namesdata-table-creates-active-binding?noredirect=1#comment36595526_23792197)

Comment: Yes, it does indirectly, due to `setnmaes`. This method, I suggested, wouldn't work. That data.table internally uses `names(x)` not being copied while setting names skipped my mind. You've to explicitly use `copy(names(x))` elsewhere and not use `names.data.table` (as it copies). If you feel strongly about it, please start a discussion on the data.table mailing list.

Comment: All right, thanks- looks like I have quite a few code changes to make